# MethodNotAllowedHttpException laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

try to make a simple insert but i get this error MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251) at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php (line 238)

this is my form in the view

```
  <form method="post" action="{{route('product.create')}}" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Product name" class="form-control input-md">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textarea">Description</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="description"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="size">Size</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="size">
                        <option selected>Choose size...</option>
                        <option value="small">Small</option>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="larg">Larg</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="category_id">Category</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <select class="form-control" id="category_id">

                        <option selected>Choose Categories...</option>
                        {{--<option value= "$categories"></option>--}}
                        <option value= "1"> men </option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="image">Image</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input id="file" name="image" class="input-file" type="file">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

my route

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'],function(){

Route::get('/' ,function(){
return view('admin.index');
})->name('admin.index');
});
Route::resource('product','ProductsController');
Route::resource('category','CategoriesController');
```

my controller

```
public function create()
{
$categories = Category::pluck('name','id');
return view('admin.product.create',compact('categories'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
$formInput = $request->except('image');
$image = $request->image;

if($image){

    $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move('images', $imageName);

    $formInput['image']=$imageName;
  }

 Product::create($formInput);
 return redirect()->route('admin.index');

}
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be:

```
action="{{route('product.store')}}"
```

The route `product.create` expects GET header for showing a register form

Comment: thanks for your replay i change the action now i don't get errors but it doesn't store anything into my DB any suggestion ?

Comment: Looks like your form request has errors. Take a look if your controller is getting all expected data. Hint: Try using controllers instead resource controller. This last one is widely used to create APIs

Comment: that what i get when i submit the form dd($request);



+request: ParameterBag {#41 ▼
#parameters: array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "2wDgwkQgH8vVmo283Aod4WbDSsHd5o3Ev7Gx8e57"
  "name" => "test name"
  "description" => "test DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription"
  "submit" => null
]
}

Comment: i get only 2 result well i have in my form more

size, image , Category and Image

Answer (score 0):

i forget to add name to the form now after adding name i get alle field except image

Answer (score 0):

I tried all above answers and still had this problem. So I found out that my model was requiring the "fillable" property:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'status', 'etc','etc2'];
```

This solved the issue and now I can post/put/delete.

Also, in my routes file instead of using one route to each action, I simply use, for example:

```
 Route::resource('user', 'v1\UserController');
```